# Eclipse C, OpenSTM32 Systems Workbench: Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project

Tags: embedded, stm32, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to run some example code for the with the DWM3000EVB board and STM32F429ZI Nucleo board. I'm working with a M1 mac (not sure if this matters).

The API for the DWM3000EVB module:
https://www.qorvo.com/products/p/DWM3000

Documentation followed: https://github.com/foldedtoad/dwm3000/blob/master/docs/Guide_for_bulding_API_Examples.pdf

Following the documentation, I downloaded Eclipse C/C++ and the ARM GNU Toolchain and set up OpenSTM32 Systems Workbench.

After adding the ARM GNU Toolchain to PATH in Eclipse, I tried to build the project. The compiling progress bar gets to about 65% and then an error window pops up:

[image]

I tried deleting the project from the workspace and re-importing, but the same error pops up.

I don't have much knowledge on how the build process, so I could be missing something super obvious. Any advice is appreciated.

Edit:
STMCubeIDE's blink example builds successfully and works as intended with my Nucleo board, which causes me to believe that Cube's toolchain is working.

Then, I tried opening the OpenSTM32 project in Cube. A dialog pop up appears saying that the conversion to a Cube project was successful, with the following EVK3000_F429_CubeMX_converter.log file:

```
Project: EVK3000_F429_CubeMX
Converter: ST System Workbench for STM32 project converter
Date: 20240118

Unknown value type "" for id gnu.c.link.option.libs on tool fr.ac6.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cross.c.linker
Option fr.ac6.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cross.cpp.linker.noexceptions is no longer supported
Option fr.ac6.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cross.cpp.linker.nortti is no longer supported
Unrecognized tool command 'as' for tool id fr.ac6.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cross.assembler
Unknown value type "" for id gnu.both.asm.option.include.paths on tool fr.ac6.managedbuild.tool.gnu.cross.assembler
```

Then, I tried to build in STMCubeIDE and got the following error dialog (some lines omitted to stay below character limit):

```
02:28:31 **** Build of configuration API_tests_examples for project EVK3000_F429_CubeMX ****
make -j7 all 
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -g3 -c -x assembler-with-cpp -MMD -MP -MF"startup/startup_stm32f429xx.d" -MT"startup/startup_stm32f429xx.o"  -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -o "startup/startup_stm32f429xx.o" "../startup/startup_stm32f429xx.s"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../platform/deca_mutex.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=c11 -g3 '-D__weak=__attribute__((weak))' '-D__packed=__attribute__((__packed__))' -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F429xx -DALL_TESTS_COMPILED -c -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Shared/dwt_uwb_driver/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/examples/examples_info" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Class/CDC/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/examples/shared_data" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/CMSIS/Include" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/MAC_802_15_4" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/MAC_802_15_8" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/platform" -O0 -ffunction-sections -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"platform/deca_mutex.d" -MT"platform/deca_mutex.o"  -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -o "platform/deca_mutex.o"


(more .o files created, no errors or warnings)


arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_spi.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=c11 -g3 '-D__weak=__attribute__((weak))' '-D__packed=__attribute__((__packed__))' -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F429xx -DALL_TESTS_COMPILED -c -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Shared/dwt_uwb_driver/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/examples/examples_info" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Class/CDC/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/examples/shared_data" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/CMSIS/Include" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/MAC_802_15_4" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/MAC_802_15_8" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/platform" -O0 -ffunction-sections -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_spi.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_spi.o"  -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_spi.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=c11 -g3 '-D__weak=__attribute__((weak))' '-D__packed=__attribute__((__packed__))' -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F429xx -DALL_TESTS_COMPILED -c -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Shared/dwt_uwb_driver/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/examples/examples_info" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Class/CDC/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/examples/shared_data" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/CMSIS/Include" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/MAC_802_15_4" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/MAC_802_15_8" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/platform" -O0 -ffunction-sections -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.o"  -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=c11 -g3 '-D__weak=__attribute__((weak))' '-D__packed=__attribute__((__packed__))' -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F429xx -DALL_TESTS_COMPILED -c -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Shared/dwt_uwb_driver/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/examples/examples_info" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Class/CDC/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/examples/shared_data" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/CMSIS/Include" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/MAC_802_15_4" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/MAC_802_15_8" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/platform" -O0 -ffunction-sections -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.o"  -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=c11 -g3 '-D__weak=__attribute__((weak))' '-D__packed=__attribute__((__packed__))' -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F429xx -DALL_TESTS_COMPILED -c -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Shared/dwt_uwb_driver/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/examples/examples_info" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Class/CDC/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/examples/shared_data" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/CMSIS/Include" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/MAC_802_15_4" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/MAC_802_15_8" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/platform" -O0 -ffunction-sections -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.o"  -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_hal_uart.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_usb.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=c11 -g3 '-D__weak=__attribute__((weak))' '-D__packed=__attribute__((__packed__))' -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F429xx -DALL_TESTS_COMPILED -c -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Shared/dwt_uwb_driver/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/examples/examples_info" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Class/CDC/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/examples/shared_data" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/CMSIS/Include" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/MAC_802_15_4" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/MAC_802_15_8" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/platform" -O0 -ffunction-sections -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_usb.d" -MT"Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_usb.o"  -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -o "Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_usb.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../main.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=c11 -g3 '-D__weak=__attribute__((weak))' '-D__packed=__attribute__((__packed__))' -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F429xx -DALL_TESTS_COMPILED -c -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Shared/dwt_uwb_driver/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/examples/examples_info" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Class/CDC/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/examples/shared_data" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/CMSIS/Include" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/MAC_802_15_4" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/MAC_802_15_8" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/platform" -O0 -ffunction-sections -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o"  -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -o "main.o"
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../stm32f4xx_hal_msp.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=c11 -g3 '-D__weak=__attribute__((weak))' '-D__packed=__attribute__((__packed__))' -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F429xx -DALL_TESTS_COMPILED -c -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Shared/dwt_uwb_driver/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/examples/examples_info" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Class/CDC/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/examples/shared_data" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/CMSIS/Include" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/MAC_802_15_4" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/MAC_802_15_8" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/platform" -O0 -ffunction-sections -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"stm32f4xx_hal_msp.d" -MT"stm32f4xx_hal_msp.o"  -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -o "stm32f4xx_hal_msp.o"
../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_usb.c: In function 'USB_WritePacket':
../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_usb.c:886:7: warning: 'packed' attribute ignored for type 'uint32_t *' {aka 'long unsigned int *'} [-Wattributes]
  886 |       USBx_DFIFO(ch_ep_num) = *((__packed uint32_t *)src);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_usb.c: In function 'USB_ReadPacket':
../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f4xx_ll_usb.c:912:5: warning: 'packed' attribute ignored for type 'uint32_t *' {aka 'long unsigned int *'} [-Wattributes]
  912 |     *(__packed uint32_t *)dest = USBx_DFIFO(0U);
      |     ^
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../stm32f4xx_hal_timebase_TIM.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=c11 -g3 '-D__weak=__attribute__((weak))' '-D__packed=__attribute__((__packed__))' -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F429xx -DALL_TESTS_COMPILED -c -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Shared/dwt_uwb_driver/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/examples/examples_info" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Class/CDC/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/examples/shared_data" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/CMSIS/Include" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/MAC_802_15_4" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Src/MAC_802_15_8" -I"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Build_Platforms/STM_Nucleo_F429/platform" -O0 -ffunction-sections -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"stm32f4xx_hal_timebase_TIM.d" -MT"stm32f4xx_hal_timebase_TIM.o"  -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -o "stm32f4xx_hal_timebase_TIM.o"


(more .o files created, no errors or warnings)


arm-none-eabi-gcc -o "DW3000_API_CubeMX.elf" @"objects.list"   -mcpu=cortex-m4 -T"../STM32F429ZITx_FLASH.ld" -Wl,-Map="DW3000_API_CubeMX.map" -Wl,--gc-sections -static -L"/Users/jeffreyyang/Desktop/DW3xxx_XR6.0C_24Feb2022/Release_XR6.0C/Software/DW3XXX_API/Sources/DW3XXX_API_rev9p3/API/Shared/dwt_uwb_driver/lib" --specs=rdimon.specs  -Wl,--whole-archive -ldwt_uwb_driver-m4-sfp-6.0.7 -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group
Finished building target: DW3000_API_CubeMX.elf
 
arm-none-eabi-size   DW3000_API_CubeMX.elf 
arm-none-eabi-objdump -h -S  DW3000_API_CubeMX.elf  > "DW3000_API_CubeMX.list"
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 102552    2856   16812  122220   1dd6c DW3000_API_CubeMX.elf
Finished building: default.size.stdout
 
Finished building: DW3000_API_CubeMX.list
 
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary "DW3000_API_CubeMX.elf" "DW3000_API_CubeMX.bin"
arm-none-eabi-size "DW3000_API_CubeMX.bin"
arm-none-eabi-size: DW3000_API_CubeMX.bin: file format not recognized
make[1]: *** [makefile:135: post-build] Error 3
make: *** [makefile:107: all] Error 2
"make -j7 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

02:28:36 Build Failed. 2 errors, 2 warnings. (took 4s.576ms)
```

Comment: You should post the build log, not just the error dialog.  Post the _text_, rather than a screenshot.

Comment: Either way I would suggest you use [STM32CubeIDE](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeide.html) for STM32 development.  It is Eclipse based and includes the GNU toolchain and STM32CubeMX tools and libraries for all STM32 parts.  In short it is set-up to work out of the box from a single install, and includes all the tools you have assembled manually.

Comment: The last line of the build log before the error dialog pops up:
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary "..\\Debug\\DW3000_API_CubeMX.elf" "..\\Debug\\DW3000_API_CubeMX.bin" 
The arm-none-eabi-gcc commands before this seem to run fine.

Comment: I will try using STM32Cube IDE.

Comment: That is still not an error message, just a command to generate an elf and binary (odd choice, normally you'd want a hex file for the address metadata).  Besides you need to edit the question and post the log _verbatim_ in `plain text_ markup.

Comment: If using CubeIDE, clearly the instructions for OpenSTM32 will not apply (at least in the detail). But your first concern should be getting code running standalone in the Nuclei board before worrying about the DWM3000EVB.

Comment: What's confusing is that I don't see an error message in the console window; all the commands seem to run fine until the arm-none-eabi-objcopy line, where the "problem occurred" pop up appears. 

I also don't get a line in the console window that looks like:
20:01:16 Build Finished. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 55ms)

Comment: Just tried to build the code in STM32CubeIDE and got an error message this time. Edited my original post.

Comment: Searched a bit online, and this error may be due to missing files containing proprietary info in the API which the manufacturer has purposefully admitted.

Comment: Understood.  Looks like a tool chain issue in the first instance with that objcopy.  In the Cube instance, it has nothing to do with any API, objcopy runs after compile and link are complete to generate a binary image suitable for flash programming.  In the Cube case objcopy succeeds and it is `arm-none-eabi-size` that fails.  The size utility is for information only, and not required by the build.  Moreover it processes the elf object code file, the .bin file contains no metadata it needs to work.  I have no idea how you got it to do that, it is certainly not generated by the CubeIDE.

Comment: Did you simply open the OpenSTM32 project in Cube?  I have no idea if that works (not familiar with OpenSTM32),  but if it does and you get the error, then clearly there is a project issue.  Note that for debug and loading over OpenOCD, you don't need a bin or hex file, it will load the elf file.  Using Cube I expected you to use a Cube generated project for your Nucleo board and avoid the "broken" OpenSTM32 project.  Just a basic test project to test the toolchain before trying anything application specific.

Comment: Remove the unnecessary `size` step, or change it to use the elf rather than the bin file.

Comment: Frustratingly though, you still steadfastly refuse to post the _entire_ log as requested.  You may _think_ it is irrelevant, but since you cannot make this work, you are not really in a position to make that call. For a start, the log fragment reports two warnings, not shown.

Comment: I apologize, the entire error log exceeds the character limit. I've edited the log to include what I think might be relevant, please let me know if there's something important I may have omitted. As described in my most recent edit, cube generated examples build and run fine. I have not yet tried your tips on size or elf.

Comment: Perhaps if it is your first project, test with something _smaller_?  Verify your toolchain and workflow before you attempt to build anything that large.  It will only slow down your fixing of toolchain issues not related to the project.

Comment: As I suggested `Finished building: DW3000_API_CubeMX.list` indicates successful build.  It is the post-build that is failing.  `size *.bin` makes no sense.  Remove it or change it to `size *.elf`.  Noting that the size information is in any case output by `objdump`, it is not clear even what that post-build step is for.

Comment: I strongly suggest also that you change the objcopy from `binary` to `ihex` (and .bin to .hex).  If you are using a bootloader so that the application image start address is not at the start of the flash, you will have to specify the _correct_ start address or offset to the programming tool if you use .bin.

Answer (score 0):

The post-build command:

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary "DW3000_API_CubeMX.elf" "DW3000_API_CubeMX.bin"
```

makes no sense.  The raw .bin file does not contain the section information required to determine the size information.  That is the cause of the error.  Although the code is built successfully and contained `DW3000_API_CubeMX.elf` / `DW3000_API_CubeMX.bin` before this needless and erroneous post-build step.

The information is already output by `objdump` in any event:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 102552    2856   16812  122220   1dd6c DW3000_API_CubeMX.elf
```

Remove the unnecessary post-build step.  You should in any event be able to load and run the .elf file (or .bin image) in any case, the error is in a post build "information only" step.